# Retrieving of data in an object from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, mongo-collection

I'm using meteor, and i have not typed "meteor remove autopublish" therefore i believe my client is able to retrieve the mongo collection "List" with no issues.

So i've added 1 object into the List collection, but i can't seem to retrieve the data from within the object.

```
List.find().fetch() //i wrote this in the console and the next few lines was the reply
[{…}]
0
:
{_id: "JqsKLoY4sx9qT8ZRR", module: "Math", user: "Tom"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

But when i wrote conosle.log(List.find({module: "Math"}).user), what is returned to me in the console was "undefined".

is there a reason for this or something I'm doing wrongly? I want to retrieve the username "Tom". Because what i truly want to do in the end is to use the value within javascript itself, for e.g - var creator = List.find({module: "Math"}).user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongo DB, if you use **find.fetch** it returns you ***array*** and so when you are trying to get the value it gives you ***undefined***.

So there is another option you can choose which is **[findOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)**, which returns ***object***.

Here's how you can do it:

```
var creator = List.findOne({module: "Math"}).user || null;
```

Comment: `find` in meteor returns a `cursor`, `find().fetch()` returns a `array` of documents and `findOne` returns 1 document or undefined